# Display products from database on filtering of price based slider in php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want implement price based slider in my project but i don't have any idea how to implement. So, anyone can help me please. I want look like like this(but it should be in php):

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Demos/772/
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/slider/examples/rangeslider/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: use `jQuery UI` + `ajax` + `MySQL` with a `limit`. Incidentally, each one of these tells you how to implement them on their respective sites.

Comment: i don't have any idea how to use. Can you help me please.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: That is why they have examples on each of the sites, to show you what to do. Just follow the code snippits and come up with something.

Comment: That example is in asp.net and i need in php. Now you can help me please.My html code is:         <label class="element-top-10 widget-title ">Budget (per day)</label>              
        <input type="text" id="range" value="" name="range" 
        onchange='document.getElementById("budget").value = document.getElementById("range").value;'/> 
        <input type="hidden" name="budget" id="budget" value=" " disabled />
        <br/>

Comment: and JS code is:   $("#range").ionRangeSlider({
  hide_min_max: true,
  keyboard: true,
  min: '<?php echo $self_drive_day_min; ?>',
  max: '<?php echo $self_drive_day_max; ?>',
  from: '<?php echo $self_drive_day_min; ?>',
  to: '<?php echo $self_drive_day_max; ?>',
  type: 'double',
  step: 1,
  prefix: "£",
  grid: true
 });

Comment: Now, can you help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, i give an example for you to start, i'm using Jquery UI for range slider :

Consider this **HTML** element for rendering slider range

```
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

**Js** code :

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
range: true,
min: 0,
max: 500,
values: [75, 300],
slide: function (event, ui) {
    // first range input(min)
    var firstValue = ui.values[0];
    // second range input(max)
    var secondValue = ui.values[1];
    $("#amount").val("$" + firstValue + " - $" + secondValue);
    // here you need to get data from database
    // request to php page with database queries for processing
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'phpProcess.php', // create this file with php+mysql(any db)
        data: {
            first: firstValue, // send this paramter
            second: secondValue // send this parameter
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function (data) { // on success request
            // remember we use echo json_encode($data); in php page
            // those data supposed to be available here
            // try console.log(data) to view data
            // on success, populate data into any type of HTML element
            // either li, table, etc... something like this

        }
    });
 }
});

// initial code to display values
$("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
" - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
```

**PHP** page

```
// retrieve data from ajax request
$first = $_POST['first'];
$second = $_POST['second'];
// this is just an example to select data between min and max
$getData = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *FROM products WHERE price BETWEEN '$first' AND '$second'");
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($getData);
// this output will available on success ajax callback
echo json_encode($data);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/cnsftum5/) - Did't added for ajax request(Using jQuery UI)

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/c75oayck/)** - Using ion.rangeSlider.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88612/discussion-on-answer-by-norlihazmey-ghazali-display-products-from-database-on-fi).